# XPath for choosing a sibling after

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I've got following xml:

```
<root>
    <a>value1</a>
    <b>value2</b>
    <c>value3</c>
    <a>value5</a>
    <d>value4</d>
    <b>value2</b>
    <b>value3</b>
    <a>value7</a>
</root>
```

I want to select the first sibling `a` after node `//b[text()='value2']` if it's not followed by an other b-node (in this case it will be `<a>value5</a>`, `<a>value7</a>` should not be selected).

What's the xpath to do that?

I'm using .net 4 and xpath 1.0

**UPDATE**

Here's where I'm coming with this from: the document I'm parsing has a very stupid structure, which can be described by

```
<root>
    <key>key-value</key>
    <some-other-nodes>some other values</some-other-nodes>
    <key>an other key value</key>
    <value>the value</value>
</root>
```

The document I've described contains following key-value pairs:
key-value->{null}
an other key value->{the value}

if the key node is repeated, it resets the `key` value. I need an xpath to select a value of a specific key. Because in the example above the second match of `//b[text()='value2']` is followed by `<b>value3</b>`, the key is reset to `value3`

Comment: The main problem here is writing code depending on the order of tags in xml.

Comment: ArsenZahray: You have two `<b>value2</b>` elements -- you must be more precise which of them you want as a base. `<a>value7</a>` is the correct answer in case the first of these b s is selected initially.

Comment: ArsenZahray: This question is contradictory -- `<a>value5</a>` is followed by a `b` -- therefore it must not be selected -- as per your requirement "I want to select the first sibling a after node `//b[text()='value2']` if it's not followed by an other b-node". Please, edit and correct.

Comment: ArsenZahray: With all due respect, your edit is incomprehensible -- do you want it to mean anything?

Answer (score 3):

**Use**:

```
   //b[text()='value2']
          /following-sibling::b[last()]
                 /following-sibling::a[1]
  |
   //b[text()='value2']
        [not(following-sibling::b)]
             /following-sibling::a[1]
```

This selects either:

1. The first following sibling `a` of the last of the `b` following-siblings of the initial `b` element, or:
2. The first following sibling of the initial `b` element, if it doesn't have any other following siblings `b`

**This can be furter simplified to**:

```
  //b[text()='value2']/../b[last()]/following-sibling::a[1]
```

**Update**:

As `//b[text()='value2']` selects *two`* elements from the provided XML documents, the OP must also specify which of these two he wants to be selected in the first location step of the XPath expression.

**Here is a more precise XPath expression** where `$k` is the number (1 or 2) in this case of the selected element `b[. = 'value2']` :

```
  (//b[text()='value2'])[$k]/../b[last()]/following-sibling::a[1]
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="k" select="1"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "(//b[text()='value2'])[$k]
      /../b[last()]
         /following-sibling::a[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <a>value1</a>
    <b>value2</b>
    <c>value3</c>
    <a>value5</a>
    <d>value4</d>
    <b>value2</b>
    <b>value3</b>
    <a>value7</a>
</root>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the element that is selected by this evaluation, is copied to the output**:

```
<a>value7</a>
```

Comment: tested in firepath, this selects `<a>value7</a>` and does not select `<a>value5</a>`, which is kind of the opposite of what I need

Comment: @ArsenZahray: You have *two* `<b>value2</b>` elements -- you must be more precise which of them you want as a base. `<a>value7</a>` *is* the correct answer in case the first of these `b` s is selected initially.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that should work:

```
//b[.='value2']/following-sibling::a[preceding-sibling::b[1][.='value2']]
```

Simply put, it selects an `a` element following any `b` element with the value `'value2'`, where the most recent `b` element has the value `'value2'`.

EDIT: Now I think about it, I'm not even sure you need the first part. Try this:

```
//a[preceding-sibling::b[1][.='value2']]
```